# How to input a date into mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, insert

Ok so i already have a few insert scripts working, however when i try and use this one nothing happens. I dont get an error or anything, it simply doesnt insert into the database. I have a feeling its the date parameter, however im unsure how to make it recognizable?

```
<?php //SETTING SESSION VARIABLES FOR ROUND 1 TEAMS AND SCORE

session_start();

  if (isset($_POST['go1'])) { // MATCHUP 1

    include_once 'dbcon.php';

    $_SESSION['t_team1'] = $_POST['team-1'];
    $_SESSION['t_team2'] = $_POST['team-2'];
    $_SESSION['s_score1'] = $_POST['score-1'];
    $_SESSION['s_score2'] = $_POST['score-2'];

    $team1winner = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['team-1']);
    $team2winner = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['team-2']);
    $date1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date-1']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO knockout (knockout_team1, knockout_team2, knockout_date)
    VALUES ('$team1winner', '$team2winner', '$date1');";

    header("Location: ../tables.php?tables=winner");
}
```

//date html

```
<input type="date" name"date-1" value="date" class="date">
```

Comment: What is `$_POST['date-1']` and what is the column type of `knockout_date`.

Comment: just added what post date 1 is, and the type is date in my database

Comment: You create the sql string, but you never actually [insert it into the database](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.** It's safer than using mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: As @aynber said, you never perform the insert. You should use MySQL's `CURDATE()` if all you want to do is insert the date when the data is inserted.

Comment: Ha @aynber caught the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are putting the SQL command in a string but you are not actually executing the command.

Second of all, if you are executing the command but you are not showing it here and your `dbcon.php` file is working properly, then it is more likely a date format issue.

Finally, you need to execute all of your commands especially `INSERT` commands in prepared statements to prevent SQL injections **winch is VERY important.**

Here how your code should look like :

```
<?php //SETTING SESSION VARIABLES FOR ROUND 1 TEAMS AND SCORE

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['go1'])) { // MATCHUP 1

    include_once 'dbcon.php';

    $_SESSION['t_team1'] = $_POST['team-1'];
    $_SESSION['t_team2'] = $_POST['team-2'];
    $_SESSION['s_score1'] = $_POST['score-1'];
    $_SESSION['s_score2'] = $_POST['score-2'];

    $team1winner = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['team-1']);
    $team2winner = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['team-2']);
    $date1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date-1']);

    $TeamsStat = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO knockout (knockout_team1, knockout_team2, knockout_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    $TeamsStat->bind_param("sss", $team1winner, $team2winner, $date1);   

    $TeamsStat->execute();
    $TeamsStat->close();

    header("Location: ../tables.php?tables=winner");
}
```

> Where `$conn` is the object of your database connection.

Since prepared statements doesn't support date type and since the date is not a free input value, the `knockout_date` column should be a string and the variable `$date1` should also be a string.

Hope that helped you.

Comment: i appreciate the great explanation, however i believe there may be a syntax error somewhere in this line $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO knockout (knockout_team1, knockout_team2) VALUES (?, ?)";

Comment: still got nothing going in database though, despite not showing any errors

Comment: @breadley Yes there was an error in my code... I mode some modifications, please try it now.

Comment: @breadley The only reason that it is not inserting even though there is no errors is because you are not executing the command.

Comment: still syntax issues with this one line `$TeamsStat = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO knockout (knockout_team1, knockout_team2) VALUES (?, ?)";`

Comment: fixed the syntax however, im back to it inputting 0's for every value into the database

Comment: @breadley Yes sorry for that... I was missing a bracket... Please try now.

Comment: ok new issue, date is inputting correctly, team names are just 0? could this be an issue with post? i can add more code if required

Comment: @breadley Ok if these are strings... Then i made a tiny modification to the code... Please try again and let me know... It should work now.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning, yes they are strings, they are created from a selection box populated by another area of my database. Ive made the changes however im still getting zeros for the team names. Is it possible to handle this in a different way? im unsure as to why its producing numbers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191039/discussion-between-breadley-and-mousa-alfhaily).

Answer (score 0):

The date format in HTML is of type dd-mm-yyyy but while inserting it into database you need to make sure its YYYY-mm-dd type. So make sure you are converting it Before inserting it

Ex :

```
  $originalDate = $yourDateVariable;
  $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Or Go through manual and find alternatives functions to convert it

Comment: still not inserting into db

Comment: Are you sure that date is converted ? try to echo it and one more thing where are actually executing that query ? i.e are you missing mysqli_query($conn,$sql); or do you performing it any other script

Comment: i was missing that script, however now ive added it all inputs are inserted as 0 in my database despite them not being this

Comment: Now that you are inserting have you checked the error logs on the server?

Comment: also make sure if you are using $_SESSION variables call session_start() in each page separately